# hg local ignore

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, hgignore

I could have sworn there was a way to keep a local ignore file in an hg repo, i.e. a file similar in function to .hgignore, but not checked into the repo.  This could be used to ignore changes to an IDE project file if different IDEs are being used, for example.  I'm having trouble finding how it's done.  Does anyone recall the details?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[This](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only) is what I was looking for.

> Add the following to the repo's .hg/hgrc:
>
> ```
> [ui]
> ignore = /path/to/repo/.hg/hgignore
> ```
>
> and create a new file .hg/hgignore beside it. This new file will be
>   untracked, but work the same as the versioned .hgignore file for this
>   specific working copy. (The /path/to/repo bit is unfortunate but
>   necessary to make it work when invoking 'hg' from within a subdir of
>   the repo.)

Comment: @Restuta, there's a (hidden) .hg folder in your repository root; create a file in there named 'hgignore' and then edit the hgrc file (in the same hidden .hg folder) as guided at the provided URL.

Comment: @ErikAllik: The link is dead (the page seems to have been blanked or something). Is there some chance you could provide these steps?

Comment: I am using Mercurial 2.8.1.  It seems they have removed this unfortunate `/path/to/repo` requirement (I got an "No such file or directory" error).  Use `ignore = .hg/hgignore` works.  So it seems now it is defaulted to the root of the repository.

Answer (score 22):

In version 3.5, setting the `ignore` property under the `ui` section changes the global ignore file.  To add additional files to be ignored, follow the advice of [Jeroen Dierckx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913/jeroen-dierckx) and set the `ignore.local` property to get the same effect as adding to `.git/info/exclude` in a `git` repository.

```
[ui]
ignore = .hgignore
ignore.local = .hg/hgignore
```

Comment: i keep getting: "skipping unreadable ignore file '': invalid mode ('r') or filename " no matter what settings i use, atm i have the above in my .hgignore file

Comment: Try using the full path to the ignored file.  I know I've had to do that in a few projects, but I can't recall if it was for the same reasons.

Comment: That "unreadable ignore" message for me was caused by the comments at the end of the line! Works fine without them, fails again when I put them back!