# How do I ignore .hgignore in my local repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hgignore

.hgignore itself is version controlled. I've added some object dirs i want to ignore but i do not want to commit these changes to .hgignore. What do i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hg local ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996562/hg-local-ignore)

Comment: The title is really misleading.  OP wants to _extend_ hgignore without putting the additional ignores into it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following to the repo's `.hg/hgrc`:

```
[ui]
ignore = /path/to/repo/.hg/hgignore
```

and create a new file `.hg/hgignore` beside it. This new file will be untracked, but work the same as the versioned `.hgignore` file for this specific working copy. (The `/path/to/repo` bit is unfortunate but necessary to make it work when invoking `hg` from within a subdir of the repo.)

Source: [Mercurial Tips and Tricks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only)

Answer (score 9):

Ironically enough, you can also just add

```
syntax:glob
.hgignore
```

To the .hgignore file itself.

Comment: if the rep is already tracking .hgignore you would need to forget it first