# Local Mercurial Ignore File

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to have a local Mercurial ignore file? Apparently the .hgignore is a file versioned as any other file. Can I have such a file next to the versioned one?

Comment: why don't you want to version it?

Comment: Because it's for instance a local folder to do some proof of concepts... But you're right, I could just version it. For instance, I have a couple of bat scripts in the root of my project with local paths in it... I do not want these scripts to be versioned. But if everyone has a few of those bat scripts, the ignore file will get stuffed...

Comment: Anyway, just wanted to know if it was possible to have a local ignore file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hg local ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996562/hg-local-ignore)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can configure a local, per-user ignore file. The location and name of this file is defined in the user-specific `.hgrc` configuration file (usually located in the home directory of the user) under the `[ui]` section, e.g.:

```
[ui]
ignore = ~/.myhgignore
```

This file should be in the same format as the repository-wide `.hgignore` file.

Reference: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui

Comment: Also on the [Tips and Tricks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only) page.

Answer (score 12):

There are several cases here, so depending on the case you'll have different possible solutions:

1. If the file or directory hasn't been added yet and if there is no `.hgignore` file, you can:

   - use `.hgignore` to filter it, and
   - you can commit `.hgignore` if this is also useful for others (e.g., *.o, etc.) or you can leave the `.hgignore` as local without commiting/pushing it, and in this case, you can even specify `.hgignore` in `.hgignore` as mentioned by msw so that your local version will also be ignored.
2. If the file or directory hasn't been added yet and if there is an `.hgignore` file that for some reason you do not want to use (commit and push), you can:

   - declare an untracked ignore file which you will use just like `.hgignore` except it will stay local. You can declare this untracked ignore file either in your repo `.hg/hgrc` or you global `$HOME/.hgrc` (see the [UI section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui) doc).
3. Finally, if the file/directory has been added to the list of tracked files, then you can't filter it with `.hgignore`: any file that is already committed cannot be ignored! You can either:

   - "`hg forget`" the file (the opposite of "`hg add`"), then do as the two first cases, or
     use the "`-X`" option as a default for status/diff/commit in your `.hg/hgrc` configuration file, e.g.,
     [defaults]
     status = -X file1 -X file2
     diff = -X file -X file2
     commit = -X file -X file3
     which will tell hg not to include these files in the use of status, diff, and commit.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: But DO NOT use forget on files shared across repos. Push's or pulls from your working repo will delete the files on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

You can also ignore `.hgignore` in your local repository:

```
$ hg clone some_repository
$ cd some_repository
$ cat > .hgignore
syntax: glob
.hgignore
$ touch foo.c bar.c
$ hg status
? foo.c
? bar.c
```

Note the conspicuous absence of the local `.hgignore` in the output of `hg status`.